# How to batch rename files recursively based on conditions

Tags: batch-file, recursion, file-rename, batch-rename

I've been searching for the past several hours and cannot find a simple method to do this.

SCENARIO:

```
PARENT_FOLDER  
----YEAR_FOLDER  
--------MOVIE1_FOLDER  
----------Movie1_Title.Ext  
----------Eng.Srt  
--------MOVIE2_FOLDER  
----------Movie2_Title.Ext  
----------02_ENG.SRT  
----------03_ENG.SRT  
--------MOVIE3_FOLDER  
----------Movie3_Title.Ext  
----------ENG.SRT  
----------ENG-SDH.SRT  
--------MOVIE4_FOLDER  
----------Movie4_title.ext  
----------Movie4.Randomstuff.SRT  
--------MOVIE5_FOLDER  
----------Movie5_title.ext  
----------randomstuff.eng.srt
```

I would like to find some way to create a batch script to recursively go through and rename the SRT files to that of the VIDEO file (AVI, MKV, or MP4).
In case where there are 2, I would like to use the largest one if possible or if the SRT name has an SDH to have it added to the end (Movie_Title.SDH.srt).

I've tried:

```
@echo off  
if exist "*SDH.srt" (  
for %%f in ("*.avi") do ren *.srt "%%~nf.SDH.srt"  
) else (  
for %%f in ("*.avi") do ren *.srt "%%~nf.srt"  
) 
for %%f in ("*.avi") do ren *.srt "%%~nf.srt"
```

The last line was to get the second file if there was one (I tried it without it as well)... This didn't work at all. I had 2 files, one with the SDH and it didn't rename it correctly.

The only thing that worked was:

```
for %%f in ("*.avi") do ren *.srt "%%~nf.srt"
```

It only renamed the first one found and it had to be run within the directory. I added the /R after the "for" but it wouldn't work recursively. I've tried to break it down and do it in steps using sample directories and file names, but that just let to a whole new level of brainhurt.
Am I even close to getting this to work?

Comment: Why not use PowerShell instead?

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to begin with PowerShell! I am barely scraping by with batch scripts. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*) DO (
 REM %%a contains directory name. Look for movie file
 FOR %%x IN (mkv avi mp4) DO (
  IF EXIST "%%a\*.%%x" FOR %%m IN ("%%a\*.%%x") DO (
   REM Look for *SDH.SRT file
   IF EXIST "%%a\*SDH.SRT" (ECHO REN "%%a\*SDH.SRT" "%%~nmSDH.SRT"
   ) ELSE (
    SET "renamed="
    FOR /f "delims=" %%s IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-s "%%a\*.srt"') DO IF NOT DEFINED renamed (
     ECHO REN "%%a\%%s" "%%~nm.SRT"
     SET "renamed=Y"
    )
   )
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

First run a recursive scan for directory-names into `%%a`. With each directory found, look for one of the required extensions in `%%x` (I'm presuming there will be only one in any directory) and if one exists, then set `%%m` to its name.

Look for `*SDH.SRT` in the directory located, and if it exists, rename it with the name-part of `%%m` before `SDH.SRT`. If there is no `*SDH.SRT` file, Clear the `renamed` flag then perform a directory-scan of the `*.srt` filenames in the directory in reverse-size order so the largest is the first listed. The `for/f` assigns the filenames found in turn and in full to `%%s` and thus the required largest-.srt file can be renamed, then set the `renamed` flag to a value so that it becomes *defined* and hence further `*.srt` files found in the directory will *not* be renamed.

I deliberately used a directory containing spaces in its name for my testing, so the processing with file/directorynames containing spaces seems correct. I'll make no comment about how missing `*.srt` files or filenames containing poison characters may fare.

Comment: Thank you so much for this ... quite complex answer! I am going to try this now. :-) Is there a way to set the sourcedir to CURRENT directory?  I have a batch script that I use (found it somewhere on here) to move all of the SRT files from the SUBS folder to the parent folder where the VIDEO file resides. It scans recursively and all I do is drop the batch file into whichever directory and it runs fine:

Comment: `@echo off  
for /d %%f in (*) do (   
    for /d %%g in ("%%f\*") do (  
        for %%h in ("%%~g\*.srt") do move "%%~h" "%%~f" >nul 2>&1  
    )  
)`   Each FOR statement should be a new line

Comment: To select the current directory, assign a value of `.` (just one dot) or of `%cd%`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!  I was just in another tab looking at the at the SOURCEDIR and saw the %cd%, so I am glad that I was at least on the right track. When I put in the entire directory where I was trying to run the batch script from as the SOURCEDIR, nothing worked. Once I changed it to a single dot, it worked perfectly. WOOHOO!!  Thanks again! I literally spent the last two days and could not get this to work.